# mysql query - 2 foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables

```
airports: airportid, airportname
flights: flightid, from_airport, to_airport
```

where `from_airport` and `to_airport` are the foreign keys.

I can join tables either on `airportid` and `from_airport` or `airportid` and `to_airport` and either I get name of `to_airport` or name of `from_airport` but I want to select both `to_airport` and `from_airport` names either in one query or at minimum cost.

Is it possible?? How??

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
flight.idflight,
flight.idairline,
flight.from_airport,
flight.to_airport,
flight.number,
airports.name AS origin
FROM
flight
Inner Join airports ON flight.from_airport = airports.idairports
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias your tables when doing the joins:

```
SELECT
  flight.idflight,
  flight.idairline,
  flight.from_airport,
  flight.to_airport,
  flight.number,
  airport_from.name AS origin
  airport_to.name AS destination
FROM flight
  INNER JOIN airports airport_from ON flight.from_airport = airport_from.idairports
  INNER JOIN airports airport_to ON flight.to_airport = airport_to.idairports
```