# php/mysql: Append 2 or more foreign keys to one 'query'?

Tags: php, mysql

---

### My solution to this is at the bottom

My issue is: I am trying to display foreign key data, but because there is more than one foreign key, I am getting a 'duplicate' query for each of the foreign keys.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV1pn.png

As you can see, I can query the correct data, but I don't know how to attach the other foreign key data to the same 'one line output'.

I've been lurking stackoverflow for a while to find an answer to my problem and I'm at a wits end. I have found quite a number of threads, such as the two links below, where I believe people are asking the same thing, however I can't seem to wrap my head around getting the solution to work in my case. From my understanding, I need to be using aliases for the tables, however I've tried multiple different interpretations of the solutions and can't recreate the solution.

[How do I merge two or more rows based on their foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754674/how-do-i-merge-two-or-more-rows-based-on-their-foreign-key)

[mysql query 2 foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504166/mysql-query-2-foreign-keys)

--

I've got two tables ('Minions and Ability'), one of which has four foreign keys linking to the other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK43s.png

This is the php code that I'm using for the query, which is mostly taken from PHP and MySQL Web Development 4th Edition (Welling, Thomson) which I purchased to get me started with php and mysql.

```
$query = "SELECT minions.name, minions.summon, minions.attack,
          minions.health, minions.race, minions.rarity, 
          minions.ability1, minions.ability2, minions.ability3, 
          minions.ability4, minions.imagebig, 
          ability.ability 
          AS ability FROM minions 
          INNER JOIN ability on 
          minions.ability1 = ability.abilityid 
          OR minions.ability2=ability.abilityid"; 

            //Only trying for 2 foreign keys to try get it to work



            $result = $db->query($query);
            $num_results = $result->num_rows;
            echo "<p>Number of items found: ".$num_results."</p>";



            for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++){
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                //echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Name: ";
                echo "<p><strong>";
                echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['name']));
                echo "</strong><br />Summoning cost: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['summon']);
                echo "<br />Attack: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['attack']);
                echo "<br />Health: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['health']);
                echo "<br />Race: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['race']);
                echo "<br />Rarity: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['rarity']);                  
                //if (stripslashes($row['ability'] != NULL)){
                    echo "<br />Abilty: ";
                    echo stripslashes($row['ability']); 
                //}
                echo "<br />";
                $imageMinion = stripslashes($row['imagebig']);  

                // $iwidth = 25;
                // $iheight = 100;
                // echo '<img src="img/'.$imageMinion.'.png" style="width:'.$iwidth.'px;height:'.$iheight.'px;">';

                //echo "<br />";
                echo '<img src="img/'.$imageMinion.'.png">';
                echo "</p>";
```

Could someone please guide me to getting this to display correctly? I've tried to follow the other solutions and just can't seem to get the alias naming correct, if I'm correct in thinking that is the solution.

========EDIT REGARDING ANSWER FROM verbumSapienti===========

I am embarrassingly unable to get your Answer to work. This is how the code looks.

```
                $query = "SELECT minions.name, minions.summon, minions.attack, minions.health, 
                      minions.race, minions.rarity, minions.ability1, minions.ability2, 
                      minions.ability3, minions.ability4, minions.imagebig, 
                      ability.ability 
                      AS ability 
                      FROM minions 
                      INNER JOIN ability 
                      ON minions.ability1 = ability.abilityid 
                      OR minions.ability2 = ability.abilityid 
                      OR minions.ability3 = ability.abilityid 
                      OR minions.ability4 = ability.abilityid"; 

            $result = $db->query($query);
            $num_results = $result->num_rows;
            echo "<p>Number of items found: ".$num_results."</p>";

            for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++){
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

                $abilities = array('ability1', 'ability2', 'ability3', 'ability4');
                foreach($abilities as $ability)
                {
                    $q = "SELECT $ability FROM minions WHERE name={$row['name']}";
                    $result = $db->query($q);
                    $row2 = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    $abilitiesArr[] = $row2[$ability];
                }

                echo "<p><strong>";
                echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['name']));
                echo "</strong><br />Summoning cost: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['summon']);
                echo "<br />Attack: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['attack']);
                echo "<br />Health: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['health']);
                echo "<br />Race: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['race']);
                echo "<br />Rarity: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['rarity']);      

                foreach($abilitiesArr as $ability)
                    {
                        $q = "SELECT $ability FROM ability";
                        $result = $db->query($q);
                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        echo "<br />Ability: $row";
                    }  


                /*if (stripslashes($row['ability'] != NULL)){
                    echo "<br />Abilty: ";
                    echo stripslashes($row['ability']); 
                }*/

                echo "<br />";
                $imageMinion = stripslashes($row['imagebig']);          
                echo '<img src="img/'.$imageMinion.'.png">';                    
                echo "</p>";
            }
```

I've tried changing around a few things and haven't had any success. As is, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in D:\Xampp\htdocs\ocduels\results.php on line 87`

Which is: 
`$row2 = $result->fetch_assoc();`

In:

```
                    $abilities = array('ability1', 'ability2', 'ability3', 'ability4');
                foreach($abilities as $ability)
                {
                    $q = "SELECT $ability FROM minions WHERE name={$row['name']}";
                    $result = $db->query($q);
                    $row2 = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    $abilitiesArr[] = $row2[$ability];
                }
```

---

**::MY SOLUTION TO THIS::**
This seems to work. I don't think its efficient, but its enough to allow me to continue learning. Thank you for all the responses. This allows me to find a 'Minion' and only have one instance of the 'Minion' when there is more than 1 Foreign Key with data.

```
                $query =   "SELECT 
                        m.name as m_name, 
                        m.summon as m_summon, 
                        m.attack as m_attack,
                        m.health as m_health,
                        m.race as m_race,
                        m.rarity as m_rarity,
                        m.ability1 as m_ability1, 
                        m.ability2 as m_ability2, 
                        aa.ability as a_ability, 
                        ab.ability as b_ability,
                        m.imagebig as m_imagebig
                        FROM minions m
                        LEFT JOIN ability aa 
                        ON m.ability1 = aa.abilityid
                        LEFT JOIN ability ab
                        ON m.ability2 = ab.abilityid";                        

            $result = $db->query($query);
            $num_results = $result->num_rows;
            echo "<p>Number of items found: ".$num_results."</p>";

            for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++){
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

                echo "<p><strong>";
                echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['m_name']));
                echo "</strong><br />Summoning cost: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['m_summon']);
                echo "<br />Attack: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['m_attack']);
                echo "<br />Health: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['m_health']);
                echo "<br />Race: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['m_race']);
                echo "<br />Rarity: ";
                echo stripslashes($row['m_rarity']);        

                if (stripslashes($row['a_ability'] != NULL)){
                    echo "<br />Ability 1: ";
                    echo stripslashes($row['a_ability']);
                }

                if (stripslashes($row['b_ability'] != NULL)){
                    echo "<br />Ability 2: ";
                    echo stripslashes($row['b_ability']);                                   
                }

                echo "<br />";
                $imageMinion = stripslashes($row['m_imagebig']);        
                echo '<img src="img/'.$imageMinion.'.png">';                    
                echo "</p>";
            }
```

Comment: do you wish to merge the rows just for display purposes? i.e. only temporarily to `echo` out as opposed to permanently stored in the database

Comment: Hi there. Yes, this is just for display purposes. Each 'Minion' may have more than one 'Ability'. If a 'Minion' has more than one 'Ability', the output is outputting the 'Minion' data each ability.
[Picture](http://i.imgur.com/L0OpmW1.png)
I am looking to have the 'Minion' displayed only once with the relevant 'Ability' data contained in just one output.

Comment: hmmn, you may need to initialise the `$db` connection inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try DISTINCT keyword to restrict duplicate values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT minions.name, minions.summon, minions.attack,
          minions.health, minions.race, minions.rarity, 
          minions.ability1, minions.ability2, minions.ability3, 
          minions.ability4, minions.imagebig, 
          ability.ability 
          AS ability FROM minions 
          INNER JOIN ability on 
          minions.ability1 = ability.abilityid 
          OR minions.ability2=ability.abilityid";
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a subquery that prints only the ability text for each ability ID contained in each minion's attributes, maybe something along the lines of:

```
$abilities = array('ability1', 'ability2', 'ability3', 'ability4');
foreach($abilities as $ability)
{
    $q = "SELECT $ability FROM minions WHERE name={$row['name']}";
    $result = $db->query($q);
    $row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()
    $abilitiesArr[] = $row2[$ability];
}
```

then replace

```
echo "<br />Abilty: ";
echo stripslashes($row['ability']);
```

with

```
foreach($abilitiesArr as $ability)
{
    $q = "SELECT $ability FROM ability";
    $result = $db->query($q);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
    echo "<br />Ability: $row";
}
```

Comment: Please note I have seen your answer and trying to implement it; any delays in feedback is because of this.

Comment: Hi there, could you please see the edit of the post for additional info regarding your reply.